# Firestore get subcollection data onDelete

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am making a fantasy football app. When a league is created, a subcollection of the league's members is stored both in the users' profiles (userProfiles/{userId}/myLeagues) and in the league itself in a `members` collection (leagues/{leagueId}/members).

When the league gets deleted, I need to roll over that `members` collection to get the ids of all the users from whom I need to then delete the league from their user profile. I am trying to use `onDelete` to get that `members` collection, but it isn't available in `deletedLeague`.

```
exports.deleteLeague = functions.firestore
    .document('leagues/{leagueId}')
    .onDelete((snap, context) => {
        const deletedLeague = snap.data();
    });
```

How can I get the `members` collection from the snapshot? Or is there another way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documents from the subcollection won't be in the document snapshot delivered to the function.   You will have to make a query for any documents in subcollections.  For example:

```
snap.ref.collection("members").get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
    // iterate the documents
})
```